# How to get the basic information from the .cer file (certificate file) and store it in the object?

Tags: javascript, file, cryptography, decode

I make a simple client-side vanilla JavaScript project. The user uploads the .cer file, and I want to decode it and show the basic info from it (issued to, valid from, etc.).

```
function showFile() {
  let fileType = file.type; // file is a global variable that stores the uploaded file
  let validExtensions = ['application/x-x509-ca-cert'];

  if (validExtensions.includes(fileType)) {
    let fileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.onload = () => {
        // here I want to call some function to decode the file
        // and create the object with the basic certificate information
    };

  } else {
    alert('Invalid file format');
    dropArea.classList.remove('active');
    dragText.textContent = 'Drag and drop your file';
  }
}
```

I know there are some libraries to do the job, but they are too complicated to me, I just need to get some info from the file. How can I do that?

Comment: This [library](https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/x509) looks pretty easy to me, I doubt there's anything simpler.

Comment: Store it in *which* object? The certificate already has the information, if you want it you can extract it again. Don't duplicate data!